# Override method (append to other methods) in this class from another java class

Tags: java, android, textview, spannable

I want to set `ClickableSpan` for a `TextView` from another class. In `ClickableSpan` I need to override two methods, `updateDrawState()` and `onClick()`. The former method is the same for all `TextViews`, but the latter, `onClick()`, is different for any `TextView`. So I want write `updateDrawState()` method only once (in the *Commons class*), not for any `TextView`. How can I achieve this?

The following code blocks clearly explain what I want:

```
public class Commons {
    ...
    public void makeSpannable(TextView tv, String text, int startIndex, int endIndex, ClickableSpan appendClickableSpan) {
        SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);
        span.setSpan({
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Activation.this, R.color.textViewClickable));
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);

            appendClickableSpan;

        }}, startIndex, endIndex, 0);
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        tv.setText(span, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class Main {
    ...
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String text = "some sample text";
    new Commons().makeSpannable(textView, text, 2, 6, new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            if (validator.checkValidation(tilCode)) ResendActivationEmail();
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, if I understand you correctly, but you probably want to create common implementation of `updateDrawState` method and several of `onClick`.

You could achive this by making abstract class where you extends `ClickableSpan` and only implement `updateDrawState` like this:

```
public abstract class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        // Your custom implementation
    }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new MyClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        // Your custom implementation
    }
};
```

---

If you insist on `Commons` class, I probably make the method static:

```
public class Commons {
    public static void makeTextViewSpannable(TextView tv, String text, int startIndex, int endIndex, MyClickableSpan span) {
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
        spannableString.setSpan(span, startIndex, endIndex, 0);
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        tv.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Commons.makeTextViewSpannable(textView, text, startIndex, endIndex, new MyClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        // Your custom implementation
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.